# apt-get -f install fails with emacs25 conflict with emacs26

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

When upgrading I get an error asking me to fix broken packages. `apt-get -f install` produces

```
...
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 emacs25-common all 25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04 [17.5 MB]
Fetched 17.5 MB in 2s (7,805 kB/s)         
(Reading database ... 265566 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../emacs25-common_25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs25-common (25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/subdirs.el', which is also in package emacs26-common 26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+18.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is `sudo apt-cache policy emacs26-common emacs25-common`:

```
emacs26-common:
  Installed: 26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+18.04
  Candidate: 26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+18.04
  Version table:
 *** 26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+18.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
emacs25-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04
  Version table:
     25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     25.2+1-6 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

Any hints on how to fix this will be gratefully received.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your apt cache. Try clearing it using `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` then try again

Comment: You should contact PPA owner about the file conflict.

Comment: @Parto Same error after clearing cache

Comment: @N0rbert `apt-get upgrade` fails while there are still broken packages. Is there any way to upgrade before the PPA is fixed?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy emacs26-common emacs25-common` to the question. What was the reason for getting Emacs from PPA? Which functionality was missed on [version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/emacs25-common) from official 18.04 LTS repository?

Comment: @N0rbert I wanted emacs26 for consistency with my other, non-Ubuntu, boxes and this wasn't in the 18.04 LTS repository. Hence the PPA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To temporarily fix the issue you can force package installation with

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04_all.deb
```

Comment: Many thanks. It installed and then `apt --fix-broken install` worked and it upgrades normally.

Comment: Thx! Worked for me as well, after updating it for the latest (25.3~2): ```sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~2.gitc09215a-kk1+18.04_all.deb```